# There is a problem throwed after command npm install mtu

Tags: node.js

Today, I want to use a frame to building my website.And I had installed node.js, then input "npm install mtu" in cmd window.There are some messages return to me:
npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No versions available for mtu
I want to know the cause of those messages happened is my operation fault or something else.

By the way, I want to set up my personal website, Could tell me what front-end frame is popular now please?

Comment: What did you expect `npm install mtu` to do? It doesn't look like such a package exists.

Comment: Uh, this component lib looks great to use, but I can't access the resource by their cdn. I try to download the mtu.min.css and mtu.min.js but failed.So I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there are no versions available to download for that package. You can go to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/mtu` and see that it gives a 404 which means there is no mtu package. Could it be you mis-typed?

As for your second question, that's too general as there are many front-end frameworks out there (React, Vue, Angular, etc) and everyone will have their own opinions on them.

Comment: Your method is so great. And I want to consult more about if I use java as my server language, React(and other like that) is used  at the same time?Or I just  use java to write html, css, js code without front-end frame.Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

[The package did exist on NPM](https://registry.npmjs.org/mtu/), but it was unpublished by the author. If you would like to use it, you can follow the instructions from the author's website: https://apprat.gitee.io/mtu-docs/#/install

You will need to follow the directions under CDN, as the directions for installing mtu as an NPM package is out of date.